# Cloning an old OS from Sata SSD to M.2 SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, disk-cloning

I have an old HP Probook with a 256GB SATA SSD. 
Now I got a new Dell XPS 15 with a 500GB M.2 SSD.

Ideally I'd want to clone my current SSD onto the new one and keep using Windows as before, but I doubt it's possible without any adapters, etc. Is this right?

Comment: Keep in mind, that both devices have different hardware. So you will have lots of redundant drivers installed which will slow down your OS. A reinstall is always preferred. Also, Windows 10 is licenced to the hardware, so in the new device, windows 10 will not be activated.

Comment: ah, I see. That's true.

Comment: You just need a machine that will let you connect both drives simultaneously. Or you can make a disk image first, then restore it to target disk (possibly on another machine).